# How to bind source of ko_autocomplete field to observableArray?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete

I am using the knockout and I want to create the autocomplete textbox field with the observableArray value.

I could bind the autocomplete and also filter the value once the page is ready but then when I add more or change the value of that observableArray source, it does not change the value of source on that autocomplete field at all. I still see the old value of observableArray on the UI but if I log inspect it, it shows me the new value.

I wonder how can we make the source of that autocomplete field take the new the value of that observableArray?

## 1st initial the value

```
     if @kind == 'location'
      @locations = if data.config?.locations?
                  $.map data.config.locations, (x) => new Location x
                 else
                  []
      @resultLocations = ko.observableArray []
      @resultLocationsUI =  ko.observableArray(@locations[0..5])
      @offset = 0
      @maximumSearchLength = data.config?.maximumSearchLength
```

## 2nd create the HTML tag and bind the value

```
   %input.autocomplete-location-input.ux-search.w25{ ko(autocomplete: :value, value: :value,update: "resultLocationsUI()", source: "resultLocationsUI()", valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', css: { error: :error }, attr: {id: "'location-input-' + code"}), type: :text }
   %button{ko(click: :loadMoreLocations)} load more
```

## 3rd load more data to the autocomplete source

```
    loadMoreLocations: =>
     startIndex = (@offset * 5)+1
     endIndex = startIndex + 5
     @offset = @offset + 1
     @resultLocationsUI(@resultLocations())
```

Comment: welcome to SO,we can't imagine your code, you should share your code please.

Comment: What language is that code in? It's neither html, nor Javascript, nor Knockout, nor jQuery, nor what-have-you. So what is it?

Comment: it is written in knockout js + coffee script + html + haml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An observable array updates *only* when the array itself changes, ***not*** when for example a property on an object that is in that array changes. It simply does not care about changes inside the array members, as long as the whole member (and thus the array) changes.

Observable arrays notify a change when an element is added or removed. They don't notify changes to properties of objects that are elements of the array. If you want *that* to happen you must make element object properties observable.